# Gdb repeated "no symbol table is loaded"

Tags: c, makefile, gdb, symbols

Alright I just can't get gdb to work despite trying quite a few solutions.

My makefile does `cc -g _________` and produces `myfilesys`

```
>gdb myfilesys
(gdb) break my_linked_list.c:90
No symbol table is loaded, use the "file" command...
(gdb) file myfilesys
Reading symbols from /home/jsexton/Work/cs492/hw3/myfilesys...(no 
debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) break my_linked_list.c:90
No symbol table is loaded, use the "file" command...
```

Can anyone see the problem? My program is broken into like 30 .c files, so I really do need to use the file:[line number] thing.

Comment: Can you show the complete command line? Did you compile files into .o before linking?

Comment: At the command line, type `file myfilesys`.  This will print the filetype.  Prints a good bit of information, make sure it says 'not stripped'.  Feel free to add the output to your question.

Comment: When it says `...(no debugging symbols found)...` when loading in your file, it means it. Check to make sure your makefile is really doing `cc -g -c` compilation of each `.c` file, not just the last one to make your `myfilesys`. If all your sources are in one directory, you can do `cc -g *.c -o myfilesys`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you claim to have compiled with `cc -g` on your executable `myfilesys`, GDB does not see any, as evidenced in your attempt to use GDB's `file` command:

> `(gdb) file myfilesys`
>   `Reading symbols from /.../myfilesys...(no debugging symbols found)...done.`

Taking you at your word that you have actually used `cc -g` for compiling `myfilesys`, this means that you have either stripped the symbols from your binaries (I find this unlikely, but I mention the possibility), or none of your object files have debug symbols. Assuming the latter, you need to apply the `cc -g -c` compilation to each individual source file. Then, each of the resulting object files will have debugging symbols, and the resulting executable will also have debugging symbols (so long as you do not strip them out after linking).

With standard makefiles such as `gmake`, this can usually be easily accomplished by augmenting the `CFLAGS` variable with `-g`. Below is a complete makefile that illustrates this with three source files:

```
CFLAGS=-g

myfilesys: a.o b.o c.o
        $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

GCC already has implicit rules that know how to create a `.o` file from the corresponding `.c` file. However, you can alter the command line arguments passed to the compiler by changing the `CFLAGS` variable. Pre-processing directives and include directories are usually passed in by augmenting the `CPPFLAGS` variable (C++ specific flags are read from `CXXFLAGS`, but `CPPFLAGS` options are passed to both the C and C++ compilers).

We need to define an explicit rule for creating the executable `myfilesys` (the `$(CC)` rule is indented with a tab character, a makefile requirement). After typing `make`, the executable will have symbols, and GDB will not report missing symbols in your executable (it may report about missing symbols from any libraries that you use):

> `(gdb) file myfilesys`
>   `Reading symbols from /.../myfilesys...done.`